# How do you hide specific content if $page = name

Tags: php, html, if-statement

How do you hide specific content if $page = name

For example:

```
<?php
if ($page=='special'){
    echo "<div>hello</div>";
}
?>
```

The above example will show the div if the $page = special. How do I do the opposite of this, hide a specific div if the $page = something?

**Edit:**

To be more specific I would like to hide my main navigation  when on the $clients page.

Do I wrap the `<nav>` with PHP or is it possible to hide a specific div if I give it a name, for example. `<nav id="clients">` the PHP would be: if `$clients` then hide the id named clients.

I should also mention that the content in question has `<?php echo $url; ?>` and the likes contained within it.

This is the exact content I would like to hide on $clients pages.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="work") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="Work">Work</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="profile") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>profile/" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="approach") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>approach/" title="Approach">Approach</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="contact") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Don't echo the div? What's generating the div that you want to hide?

Comment: Change `==` to `!=`.  Unless you mean "hide" in the sense of CSS `display: none` (or some javascript to hide the div), then there is no option in PHP other than to not output the element in question.

Comment: Try **if(!$page){ YOUR CODE }**

Answer (score 1):

> hide a specific div if the $page = something?

```
if ($page !='special'){
    echo "<div>hello</div>";
}
```

You just echo it if `$page` is different from something.

If you want, you can also echo it anyway but as 'hidden' if that's what you're trying to achieve.

```
if ($page =='special'){
     echo "<div>hello</div>";
} else {
     echo "<div style='display:hidden;'>hello</div>";
}
```

This way, the div will be in the DOM anyway and you can show it later on without reloading the page using JavaScript.

Comment: To be more specific I would like to hide my main navigation <nav> when on the $clients page.

Comment: Do I wrap the <nav> with PHP or is it possible to hide a specific div if I give it a name, for example. <nav id="clients"> the PHP would be: if $clients then hide the clients ID.

Comment: once you echo out a div, it is not possible to hide it with PHP: you must use client side code (and it will still be visible in the code from the browser). The only way to prevent HTML code to be submitted to the client is to wrap it in IF statement as shown above.

Comment: Sidenote: The syntax is `display:none;` not `hidden`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it on every other page that is not special

```
<?php
if ($page!='special'){
    echo "<div>hello</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: While this looks like it should work it doesn't, and I think it's because I have PHP content inside the div in question?