# Hiding content with PHP

Tags: php

How can I hide the bellow content which is found in the header when on `<?php $page = "clients";?>`

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="work") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="Work">Work</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="profile") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>profile/" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="approach") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>approach/" title="Approach">Approach</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($page=="contact") echo "class=\"current\"" ?> href="<?php echo $url; ?>contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not enough information here. `header` is undefined.

Comment: How is this different from your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340718/how-do-you-hide-specific-content-if-page-name

Comment: header.php which is an include. My previous question wasn't specific enough to be answered.

Comment: @dan: then edit the previous question. don't post duplicates.

Comment: I did edit the previous question but it went unseen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $page = 'work'; // This has to be above the use of $page; ?> 
<?php if($page == 'work') { ?><strong>Show This</strong><?php } ?>
```

or for hiding

```
<?php $page = 'clients') { ?>
<?php if($page != 'clients') { ?>
     <div id="nav">
         <ul>
             <li>Hello</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

for dynamically working out what the page is so you're not relying on the $page; variable check out

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
</pr>
```

You have options to use then, like $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

So:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == 'work.php') { ?><strong>Show This</strong><?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am trying to hide the contents of <nav></nav>

Comment: Based on what criteria? @DanHewitt If it's the page name check out the $_SERVER print out and you'll be able to see the name as I demonstrated above.

Comment: Based on <?php $page = "clients";?>

Comment: When on that page I would like to hide the <nav> in it's entirety.

Comment: So wrap you nav HTML like this <?php if($page != "clients") { > NAV HTML HERE <?php } ?>

Comment: That gives me a syntax error.

Comment: missing a ? before "NAV HTML" should be ?> NAV HTML HERE @DanHewitt

Comment: Bingo! <?php if($page != "clients") { ?> is correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
if($page == "clients"){
    //show content here
} else {
    //Don't show
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can place a PHP tag within another tag so this wouldn't work?

Comment: What!?!? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Could you show me your example in full by using my above content please?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) == "YourPageName") {    
//do something    
}
```

If you want to consider the page extensions as well, you can use the following instead:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "example.php") {
//do something
}
```

Comment: All pages are index.php placed in specific folders. Can a PHP script not work from <?php $page = "clients";?>